# After build angular 8 app for prod style is empty

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have angular8 app with multiple project. 
When I go in any of project and run

`ng build admin-app --prod --stats-json`

I get all of these files

```
chunk {6} polyfills-es5.7e18553637310a6d0098.js (polyfills-es5) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} polyfills-es2015.0adb055cca906f38cae6.js (polyfills) 36.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} 1-es2015.1421395be5fd17734d71.js () 30.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1-es5.1421395be5fd17734d71.js () 30.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2-es2015.54c5263f8b3d6cff2b93.js () 23.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2-es5.54c5263f8b3d6cff2b93.js () 23.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.02e4ef3fa55cfa8b3500.js (runtime) 2.38 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.02e4ef3fa55cfa8b3500.js (runtime) 2.38 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {4} main-es2015.c3d598a1976111504efe.js (main) 904 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} main-es5.c3d598a1976111504efe.js (main) 1.01 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es2015.6e379b04c2dc601aa4ad.js () 67 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es5.6e379b04c2dc601aa4ad.js () 67.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3-es2015.931659cc28f8b777d441.js () 43.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3-es5.931659cc28f8b777d441.js () 43.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es2015.b7b89698d675e0d00f4b.js () 41.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es5.b7b89698d675e0d00f4b.js () 41.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es2015.03e1846c23707360191b.js () 147 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es5.03e1846c23707360191b.js () 148 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es2015.c5a8321ecf44383c32c4.js () 45.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es5.c5a8321ecf44383c32c4.js () 46 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} styles.e72195ebd952f53be899.css (styles) 31 bytes [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-11-27T10:23:42.642Z - Hash: b5cfecab3884623ea265 - Time: 42079ms
```

And when I run the app with 
`npx serve`

I get working application but without `angular-material` styles and without my custom scss files...

In file `styles.e72195ebd952f53be899.css` I only have style from my root `style.scss`.

```
body,html{margin:0;height:100%}
```

**If I build my root app I get everything worked correctly...** 
Now, the problem is, when I **want to build one of my projects** inside folder `projects` in the root, in this case, angular-cli don't take .scss files from project

First I have `.css` styles in my app, but now I convert all files to `.scss`.
Is there any problem with that? 
Do I need to somewhere tell the angular compiler to compile all scss to css?

These are the steps I made to convert to .scss

- `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`
- After I rename all css to scss in all applications.
- In angular.json file, I change all references to style.css files to must change to .scss, also, in all styleUrls field in the @Component decorator in component.ts files i change from css to scss

And I have service workers in app, if you need this info. 
I don't have any error message in the console.

Comment: did you have the same problem building for NON prod?

Comment: If I use `ng build` or `ng build --prod` I have the same problem

Comment: have you seen in your components if the `stylesUrl` are changed?

Comment: also check the `angular.json` file if you have correct schematics strings `"@schematics/angular:component"` with value `"style": "scss"` and `"styles"` with value `"src/styles.scss"`

Comment: @Emanuele i already check, everything is fine... pls, check my question again... I made sam edits